# Filter A Dataframe Column based on the the values of another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have two dataframes,

```
   **A**                   **B**

| a | b | c |                |a|

| 1 | 2 | 3 |                |1|
```

I want to filter the contents of dataframe A based on the values in column a from Dataset B. The equivalent where clause in SQL is like this

```
WHERE NOT (A.a in (select a from B)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find that dupe target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep all the rows in the left table where there is a match in the right, you can use the `leftsemi` join. In this case, you only want to keep values if there is **not** a match in the right table, in that case you can use a `leftanti` join:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3),(2,3,4)], ["a","b","c"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2)], ["a","b"])

df.join(df2,'a','leftanti').show()
```

df

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

df2

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

result

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

Hope this helps!